# 'DLLVERSIONINFO' Compile error after updating project to VS2012 from VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008

I have a very old C++ application that over the years, and before my time, the source code has been migrated many times.  It now builds and compiles under VS2008.  I decided to migrate to VS2012, after doing so, I now receive the following compiler error:  error C2371: 'DLLVERSIONINFO' : redefinition; different basic types

I have not changed one single line of code.  I simply updated the project from VS2008 to VS2012.

After visiting [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and playing around a little bit, I commented out the last part of the struct “DLLVERSIONINFO” at the very end of the _DllVersionInfo  struct.

Now the project compiles and run!!!

My questions are as follows:
1)  Does that mean that Microsoft changed the way this struct works in VS2012?
2)  What sort of problems could I possibly run into if I leave the commented section out for good?

Source code below.

```
// 1998 Microsoft Systems Journal
//
// If this code works, it was written by Paul DiLascia.
// If not, I don't know who wrote it.
// http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0498/c0498.aspx

#ifndef __MODULEVER_H
#define __MODULEVER_H

// tell linker to link with version.lib for VerQueryValue, etc.
#pragma comment(linker, "/defaultlib:version.lib")

#ifndef DLLVERSIONINFO
// following is from shlwapi.h, in November 1997 release of the Windows SDK

typedef struct _DllVersionInfo
{
    DWORD cbSize;
    DWORD dwMajorVersion;                   // Major version
    DWORD dwMinorVersion;                   // Minor version
    DWORD dwBuildNumber;                    // Build number
    DWORD dwPlatformID;                     // DLLVER_PLATFORM_*
} /*DLLVERSIONINFO*/; // commented out this part

// Platform IDs for DLLVERSIONINFO
#define DLLVER_PLATFORM_WINDOWS         0x00000001      // Windows 95
#define DLLVER_PLATFORM_NT              0x00000002      // Windows NT

#endif // DLLVERSIONINFO

// value must pair with static LPCTSTR Keys[]  in method CString
//  CMainVersion::GetFile_VS_VERSION_INFO(...)
typedef  enum  {
    eCompanyName = 0,
    eFileDescription = 1,
    eFileVersion = 2,
    eInternalName = 3,
    eLegalCopyright = 4,
    eOriginalFilename = 5,
    eProductName = 6,
    eProductVersion = 7,
    eAllInfo = 8
} E_VS_VERSION_INFO;

class CModuleVersion : public VS_FIXEDFILEINFO 
{
protected:
 BYTE* m_pVersionInfo;  // all version info

 struct TRANSLATION {
    WORD langID;            // language ID
    WORD charset;           // character set (code page)
} m_translation;

public:
 CModuleVersion();
 virtual ~CModuleVersion();
 static CString GetModuleVersion();
 static CString GetModuleHistory();

 BOOL  GetFileVersionInfo(LPCTSTR modulename);
 CString    GetValue(LPCTSTR lpKeyName);
 static BOOL DllGetVersion(LPCTSTR modulename, DLLVERSIONINFO& dvi);
};

class CMainVersion 
{
public:
 CMainVersion();
 virtual ~CMainVersion();

static CString GetFileVersion(const CString & csModuleName);
static CString GetFile_VS_VERSION_INFO(const CString & csModuleName,
E_VS_VERSION_INFO eInfo);
static CString GetFileAndDllVersion(const CString & csModuleName);
static CString GetAllVersions();
};
#endif
```

Comment: `// 1998 Microsoft Systems Journal`  Why are you using a 17 year old header file?  Second, if you leave the version info out of your DLL, you won't be able to know what version your DLL is when you use the various Windows tools and utilities.

Comment: "Why are you using a 17 year old header file?"  Because that is what I was  given.  Sad thing is, there are some that are older.  I have yet to write one line of code in this project.  At some point, all these applications will have to be re-written. My job is to perform maintenance until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, Microsoft added their own declaration of `DLLVERSIONINFO` (in shlwapi.h) sometime between VS2008 and VS2012.  You should not be declaring it manually anymore, just use `#include <shlwapi.h>` instead.

Either way, `#ifndef DLLVERSIONINFO` would never have worked, as `DLLVERSIONINFO` is not declared using a `#define` statement.  If you want to conditionally define `DLLVERSIONINFO` based on compiler version, use `_MSC_VER` instead, eg:

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1700 // 1700 == VS2012
#include <shlwapi.h>
#else
// following is from shlwapi.h, in November 1997 release of the Windows SDK

typedef struct _DllVersionInfo
{
    DWORD cbSize;
    DWORD dwMajorVersion;                   // Major version
    DWORD dwMinorVersion;                   // Minor version
    DWORD dwBuildNumber;                    // Build number
    DWORD dwPlatformID;                     // DLLVER_PLATFORM_*
} DLLVERSIONINFO;

// Platform IDs for DLLVERSIONINFO
#define DLLVER_PLATFORM_WINDOWS         0x00000001      // Windows 95
#define DLLVER_PLATFORM_NT              0x00000002      // Windows NT

#endif // _MSC_VER
```